# I Need To Compare 4 Dates Against Today's Date To Get A Yes Or No Result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I have 4 cells on the same row that are either blank or contain a date (YYYY-MM-DD), which I need to compare to today's date.  If any one cell is blank or occurs in the past, I want the result to reflect a "No" Answer.

To get a "Yes" result, all four cells must occur today or in the future.

I tried a nested IF-THEN statement, but am getting a "Yes" if at least one cell has today's date or later.

Here's my attempt:

```
=IF(J4>=TODAY(),"Yes",IF(K4>=TODAY(),"Yes",IF(L4>=TODAY(),"Yes",IF(M4>=TODAY(),"Yes","No"))))
```

resulting in a "Yes" in cell N4

However, in my example, J4 and L4 both have dates that occur in the future, whereas K4 and M4 are blank, so the answer I want here is a "No".  In addition, if all of cells are blank or all have dates that have already passed, I want a "No" result as well.  Also, if some dates are current, but others are in the past, I also want a "No" result.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Calculation Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can use COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(J4:M4,">="&TODAY())=4,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Or you can use AND() **IF the cells are truly blank and NOT a formula that returns `""`**:

```
=IF(AND(J4:M4>=TODAY()),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, Scott!  I thought about using COUNT, but wasn't sure of the syntax.  I didn't think about COUNTIF.

Comment: I got your answer to work, Scott, but I just edited my original question to ask another.  If you, or anyone else, has time, maybe you could take another look.  Basically, I have another column that I would like to automatically default to today's date, if anything on that specific line gets edited/added or changed in some other way.

Comment: That is not appropriate for this forum.  Once you receive answers, changing the question invalidates the answer.  Instead ask a new question.  Please revert this question back to the original.  It opens me up for down votes.

Answer (score 0):

the most succinct method I can think of is to use AVERAGE with comparison in IF

blank cells will be set to the serial number of 0 if formatted as dates and will display as 01/01/1900

=IF(AVERAGE(range)<TODAY(),"No","Yes")